# indexoutofboundsexception for loop and field

Tags: java, eclipse, string, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class Task { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text ="a subject is the noun that is doing the main verb."; 
        int[] field = new int[26];
        int xy = 0; //xy will be the total number of the letter in the sentence


        char cd = 'a';
        for (int ef = 0; ef<= 25; ef++){
            for (int ab = 1; ab<= text.length(); ab++){
                    if (cd == text.charAt(ab)){ // Eclipse says that this line has problem (at CopyOfAufgabe_2.main(CopyOfAufgabe_2.java:13)
                        field[ef]=field[ef]+1;
                        xy++;
                    }
                }
            cd++;
            }
    }
}
```

#### ``There are two purposes in this task:

```
1. find the total number of letters in the sentence
2. find the number of respective letter (i.e. how many "a"s, how many "b"s, etc. The numbers are assigned to the field created in the fifth line (one number for each object)) (It is assumed that every letter in the sentence is not capitalized.)
```

error message displayed:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 42
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at CopyOfAufgabe_2.main(CopyOfAufgabe_2.java:13)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (int ef = 0; ef<= 25; ef++){`

should be

`for (int ef = 0; ef< 25; ef++){`

An array of 25 elements has indices from 0 to 24.

`for (int ab = 1; ab<= text.length(); ab++){`

should be

`for (int ab = 0; ab< text.length(); ab++){`

The characters of a String with `length()` characters have indices from 0 to `length()-1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And sorry for the misunderstanding. The array should have 26 elements (since there are 26 letter in English alphabet), I got the set-up of the array wrong. Just corrected it... However, it still does not work.

Comment: With exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Aabbccc I've tested your code. It works if you fix both mentioned problems.

Comment: @Aabbccc Did you fix the second problem? (`ab<= text.length();`)

Comment: @Eran Thank you for the second suggestion. It works now.

Comment: @Aabbccc You're welcome. I Erans answer is correct, then accept it by clicking the checkmark beneath the vote counter.

Comment: Thank you. Being new to stackoverflow... and Java.